# How to executing the following command in Android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to create a new App Linking object for the sharing posts of my android application to facebook sdk. I look around and I found this. My App is "Mobile-Only". So, it seems I supposed to send this command to facebook. How can I send this ?

FYI; I have set-up Facebook App and successfully integrated "Sharing Post on Facebook via Android App". Seems I am quite new on Graph API of Facebook SDK.

Thanks.

```
curl https://graph.facebook.com/app/app_link_hosts \
-F access_token="APP_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
-F name="Android App Link Object Example" \
-F android=' [
{
  "url" : "sharesample://story/1234",
  "package" : "com.facebook.samples.sharesample",
  "app_name" : "ShareSample",
},
]' \
-F web=' {
"should_fallback" : false,
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this page:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/app/app_link_hosts

There is sample code for Android SDK under **Publishing**

Comment: Yes, I am looking into it. Do you have any idea what to replace the "app_link_host" ? "app_name" I have replaced.

Comment: "app_link_host" should be Facebook Graph API path, it shouldn't be replaced. For Android, you should add field **android** into Bundle params.

Comment: Hi Calvinfly, your answers were quite useful for me. Thanks a lot for that. But, still, I want to know how to execute the above command. So far, I understand those are "cURL". Do you have any idea about that ?

Comment: Oh, sorry about my misunderstanding. I thought you want to run those command in Android.
The command you posted is Linux command. In Windows OS, you may use **Cygwin** to run those command.